# Nginx 405 Not allowed when another site redirects to my Ionic webiste

Tags: nginx, ionic3

I have an app that connects various payment gateways. When payment gateway navigates back to my site using url example.com/after-payment-success or example.com/after-payment-failed I get a 405 not allowed from Nginx.

If I visit the page direct from my browser there is no problem also when I refresh the exact same page with the 405 error it loads perfectly fine.

It seems to be related to programmatic redirection to my site from payment gateway.

Details: Site is hosted in a AWS which redirects to http Nginx .Also the payment request goes from my ionic App to another apache server first then to payment gateway.While returning PG redirects to apache and then to my app

Below is the configuration

```
proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: What type of HTTP requests are used by this gateways, `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: Post request is used

Comment: Can you show full `server` block of your nginx config?

Comment: updated in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `location` block instead:

```
location / {
    error_page 405 =200 $uri;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Since you don't use the functionality of `ngx_http_proxy_module`, you don't need that `proxy_set_header` directives (though they are not the reason of this error).

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan, it worked!! I have one more query, I have one more joomla website which opens up on hitting suppose  example.com/administrator and now it has stopped working , it is getting redirected to my ionic site and not the joomla ! So how can I handle that in my nginx configuration?

Comment: @Priyanka It stopped working after you applied this changes to your config?

Comment: yes. So this is something like  for payment success and failure it should redirect to our ionic website pages(which  I am able to after adding fix suggested by you) and for '/administrator' it should open up joomla page , the domain is same.

Comment: @Priyanka Return your `proxy_set_header` directives back. If it does not help, add your full `server` block to your question.

Comment: we haven't added any configuration for that , I have the only block posted in my question above

Comment: @Priyanka Do you added back those `proxy_set_header` directives? Does it help?

Comment: no it didn't work!! but what will happen if I get actual 405 error, will it also consider 200 and pass?

Comment: @Priyanka Yes, it is. You can explicitly limit allowed methods with [`limit_except`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except) nginx directive. And this single line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` should not interfere with your joomla site anyways, if it worked without this line, it should work with this line too.